# Generating and naming powered transformations of variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, paste

I'm a newbie with R (coming from the Stata world).  To save myself time, I'm trying to use the loop function to generate powers of an existing column of data within a data frame (that is roughly 70,000 rows long). The existing column is called OrdersData$timecount; I'm trying to automate making 9 powers of it, i.e. OrdersData$timecount2=OrdersData$timecount^2, OrdersData$timecount3=OrdersData$timecount^3, and so on.  I'm trying to do it all in one for command:

```
i<-1;
for(i in 1:9){paste(OrdersData$timecount,"[i+1]",sep="")<-OrdersData$timecount^[i+1]}
```

I'm getting an error called "text".  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One question to ask yourself is "Why am I doing this?"  If the answer is that you think it is necessary to do this before another task you can mention that in the question.  A lot of times new users of R try to do things because they needed to do that in a different program before doing the task they're interested in.  That might not be necessary in R so please always keep the big picture in mind and let us know what your *actual* goal is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error is coming from assigning `<-` a variable to a string (not a variable). You can "create" variables by using the `assign` command. See `?assign` and `?get` (valuable learning experiences to read both given your present attempt)

But you can use a for loop that will match much of what you were attempting to create.

```
for(i in 1:9) {
OrdersData[paste("timecount",i+1,sep="")] <- OrdersData$timecount^i
}
```

Sometimes thinking takes longer than typing:

```
OrdersData$timecount2 <- OrdersData$timecount^2
OrdersData$timecount3 <- OrdersData$timecount^3
OrdersData$timecount4 <- OrdersData$timecount^4
OrdersData$timecount5 <- OrdersData$timecount^5
OrdersData$timecount6 <- OrdersData$timecount^6
OrdersData$timecount7 <- OrdersData$timecount^7
OrdersData$timecount8 <- OrdersData$timecount^8
OrdersData$timecount9 <- OrdersData$timecount^9
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to stop thinking in `stata` and use `R` idioms.

Here is an approach that works (and will stop you thinking in `stata`)

```
  DF <- data.frame(timeCount = seq(0,1,l=3))
  # use lapply to create a list
  # with elements timeCount^1, timeCount^2, .... etc
  powered <- lapply(1:9, function(x,y) x^y, x = DF$timeCount)
  # give names that make sense
  names(powered) <-  paste0('timeCount',1:9)
  # convert to a data.frame
  newDF <-  as.data.frame(powered)

  newDF



  timeCount1 timeCount2 timeCount3 timeCount4 timeCount5 timeCount6 timeCount7 timeCount8  timeCount9
1        0.0       0.00      0.000     0.0000    0.00000   0.000000  0.0000000 0.00000000 0.000000000
2        0.5       0.25      0.125     0.0625    0.03125   0.015625  0.0078125 0.00390625 0.001953125
3        1.0       1.00      1.000     1.0000    1.00000   1.000000  1.0000000 1.00000000 1.000000000
```

@Brandon's answer may be easier to follow, but growing a data.frame within a loop will copy the data.frame (internally) at least once each time.

Comment: Great answer. If you could split it into several rows, it would be easier for newcomers to follow.